# Add dot (.) on datepicker day names with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am customizing the datepicker, and I was able to do everything except one thing. In my calendar the day goes like this: Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa, 
They are written in a span like this:

```
<span title="Sunday">Su</span>
```

Can I add the dot after every name? I tried with javascript, but I can't find a way to catch that span.. it has no id, no class. I tried with

```
$('span').attr('Sunday').append(".");
```

and a lot of combinations, but nothing seems to work. If anyone has done this stuff, please share your wisdom.

Comment: It is unclear what datepicker you are using, and there are several. If you create a [mcve] I'll help you add the dots to it.

Comment: Can't understand the question entirely, but it seems like the `attr` function is not been used correctly!

Comment: May be you can just explain the scenario and what are you trying to really do.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax to add a dot to the posted `span` would be

```
$('span[title="Sunday"]').each(function(){
  $(this).text($(this).text + '.')
});
```

This will change it for all spans with title `Sunday`.

However, I advise against it. Instead of changing the value, you can just append a `.`(dot) visually, with CSS, without modifying the value in the textnode:

```
span[title="Sunday"]::after {
  content: '.';
}
```

In order to make it more effective and not have to specify the day names, we could use a selector that matches the parent of the day spans, which you haven't provided yet, something like:

```
.daysContainer > span[title]::after {
   content: '.';
}
```

If all day `span`s are direct children of a container with the class `daysContainer`.

**Note:** As [@Baruch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/554021/baruch) well pointed out, you could target all spans containing the string `day` in their `title` attribute with `span[title*=day]` resulting in:

```
span[title*="day"]::after {
  content: '.';
}
```

However, if, for example, you have a title containing *today* or *yesterday*, they will also be affected, so it might be a tad too general.

Comment: Everthing works, I will use the css code. I now understand better what this ::after stand for in css. And the jquery look great also. Thank you for your help!

Comment: you cold also do `span[title*=day]` to select all the titles that contain "day" in the word

Answer (score 0):

You could do a loop through stated days and then concatenate the value into a jQuery selector.

Example:

HTML

```
<span title="Sunday">Su</span>
<span title="Monday">Mo</span>
<span title="Tuesday">Tu</span>
<span title="Wednesday">We</span>
<span title="Thursday">Th</span>
<span title="Friday">Fr</span>
<span title="Saturday">Sa</span>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  days.forEach(function(day) {
    $('span[title='+day+']').append('.');
  });
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/as64jw3d/1/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which datepicker you're using, so let's assume you're talking about jQuery datepicker, a simple way to do this (and to customize any text/names displaying) is to change the i8n definition  like below :

```
datepicker.setDefaults({
        closeText: "Done",
        prevText: "Prev",
        nextText: "Next",
        currentText: "Today",
        monthNames: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
        monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        dayNamesShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
        dayNamesMin: ["Su.", "Mo.", "Tu.", "We.", "Th.", "Fr.", "Sa."], // Note that I already added the dots after the mini day names notation
        weekHeader: "Wk",
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ""
    }
);
```

You can use the same approach with other plugins.

Comment: This is also very helpfull for further customization!

Comment: It's a global customization so you don't have to apply the change in every page.